# WPF TabControl Change selected tab

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, selecteditem

Hi I have two questions.

1. How do I programatically change the selected tab in a WPF Tab control from one tab to another.
2. How would I get a reference to this "other tab" in which I want to set the selected tab?

Answer (score 28):

1. Use [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx) or [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) or by changing the value of the property to which those properties are bound
2. If you're using [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx), you don't need a reference to the tab. If you're using [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx), you need a reference to the *data item* for that tab - not the tab itself. If you've bound one of those properties to another property, you change that property rather than changing the property on the `TabControl`.

Comment: One minor thing - If you are setting this inside a mouse event and no Click() event is available, use a mouse UP event and not a DOWN event.  It will not work if you set the SelectedIndex inside a down event where the event is contained in the TabControl.